# Verification Fingerprint (DigitalPersona - FingerPrint) in Delphi ActiveX component

Tags: delphi, fingerprint

How to use DPFPVerification class in Delphi, because it become error 'undeclare identifier' even if already import activeX control (DigitalPersona One Touch for Windows Control 1.0, it will install class TDPFPVerificationControl and TDPPFEnrollmentControl)

Actually this working with C++ and Visual Basic, but I need to use it using Delphi 7.

Steps are :

1. Install One Touch DigitalPersona SDK,
2. Import ActiveX Control from
   Delphi 7

[image: DPFPVerificationControl]

[image: DPFPEnrollmentControl]

[DigitalPersona One Touch SDK](http://www.4shared.com/get/MGW5EHxg/DPOTWSDK161.html)

[Manual Book (in VB & C++ ONLY, no Delphi Codes)](http://www.google.com/url?q=http://www.digitalpersona.com/uploadedFiles/Support/Reference_Material/Guides/SDK_Guides/One-Touch-for-Windows-SDK-COM-ActiveX-Developer-Guide.pdf&sa=U&ei=Y4YIUtmzE8uUrAfP24HQDQ&ved=0CBoQFjAA&usg=AFQjCNFzTnpY8n17rVrLsX5Rl_GC8H4qyg)

VISUAL BASIC codes :

```
// NOT ERROR, but error in Delphi ( var Ver:DPFPVerification; )
Dim Ver As DPFPVerification  

Private Sub Form_Load()
  ' Create DPFPVerification object.
  Set Ver = New DPFPVerification
End Sub


Private Sub DPFPVerificationControl1_OnComplete
(ByVal Ftrs As Object, ByVal Stat As Object)  

  Dim Res As Object
  Dim Templ As Object
  ' Compare feature set with all stored templates.

  For i = 0 To 10
    ' Get template from storage.
    Set Templ = MainForm.GetTemplate(i)

    If Templ Is Nothing Then
    Else
      ' Compare feature set with particular template.
      Set Res = Ver.Verify(Ftrs, Templ)
      ' If match, exit from loop.
      If Res.Verified = True Then Exit For
    End If
  Next

  If Res Is Nothing Then
    Stat.Status = EventHandlerStatusFailure
    Exit Sub
  ElseIf Res.Verified = False Then
    ' If non-match, notify caller.
    Stat.Status = EventHandlerStatusFailure
    MainForm.Verified.Value = 0
  Else
    MainForm.Verified.Value = 1
  End If

  ' Show false accept rate.
  MainForm.FAR.Caption = Res.FARAchieved

End Sub
```

DELPHI codes :

```
uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, OleCtrls, DPFPCtlXLib_TLB;

var
  frm_verification: Tfrm_verification;
  Ver:DPFPVerification; << ERROR : 'undeclare identifier DPFPVerification'
```

[image: Two DigitalPersona Class]

[DPFPCtlXLib_TLB.pas](http://www.mediafire.com/download/j942q3wwye7i56g/DPFPCtlXLib_TLB.pas)

Comment: Can you provide your Delphi source codes to be able to see where your import goes wrong? Can you import the active component into the Delphi environment? Can you insert it into your application? Do you see it in the visual form editor? Can you instantiate it from code?

Comment: I already add screenshots above for activeX controls in activeX page of VCL

Comment: Environment Options | Library Path | C:\Program Files\DigitalPersona\One Touch SDK\COM-ActiveX

Comment: Your form has a variable of TDPFPVerificationControl. This is the variable to use AFAICT.

Comment: No, DPFPVerification and DPFPVerivicationControl is different class. See the Visual Basic codes above.

Comment: Clearly DPFPVerification is not defined. We can't see DPFPCtlXLib_tlb, since you do not include that file.

Comment: No, i included DPFPCtlXLib_TLB in Uses. See the Delphi codes above.

Comment: Yes, but we cannot see the source. Have you read the `One Touch for Windows SDK COM‐ActiveX DeveloperGuide`?

Comment: API reference in the manual are for VB and C++ developer, not for Delphi developer.

Comment: Without seeing DPFPCtlXlib-tlb.pas there is no way to help.

Comment: I already upload a DPFPCtlXlib_tlb.pas, hope somebody can help me to solve it. Still mystery....